# I sent XMR from wallet 1 to wallet 2 and it says 0 coins

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id

So i've been using monero(https://www.getmonero.org)version (0.16.0.2 (Qt 5.12.8) for awhile now. I updated to the latest 0.16.0.2) same day i made the transfer.

Never had problem sending funds from one wallet to another. Well this time the funds from wallet 1 isn't showing up in wallet 2.

In wallet 1(fully synced) transaction history shows everything perfectly, I got the transaction ID, total XMR sent, fee's, 460 confirmations, and the output address(which i checked plenty times) is all correct.

But when I login to wallet 2(fully sync), I see no incoming transactions, its been 14 hours since the funds have been sent.

I’ve done everything no differently from other times. What’s going on, where did my funds go?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what i did was completely delete the log and did a full restore wallet and let it fully resynchronized and the funds show now.